# How to create RDLC report with joined tables?

Tags: vb.net, reporting, rdlc

I'm trying to create a report that will display my table that has joins from different tables that looks likes this,

```
select * from tblproduct As p inner join tblbrand As b On p.bid = b.brandid inner Join tblclassification As c On p.cid = c.classid inner Join tblformulation As f On p.fid = f.formid inner Join tblgeneric As g On p.gid = g.genericid inner Join tbltype As t On p.tid = t.typeid
```

My table consist of 8 columns and 4 of it is column id's for joins, I can succesfully use the query when im trying to display to datagridview but when I try this in reportviewer it doesn't work and gives me error: `"Object reference not sent to an instance of an object"`. This is what I tried,

```
Public Class frmInventoryReport

    Public Property strReport2 As String
    Private Sub frmInventoryReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.tblproductTableAdapter.Fill(Me.groceryDataSet.tblproduct)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

        Dim rptDataSource As New ReportDataSource

        Try
            With Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
                .ReportPath = "D:\VisualBasic\EELPOS - Copy\EELPOS\Report3.rdlc"
                .DataSources.Clear()
            End With

            Select Case strReport2
                Case "Report3"

                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    Dim sqlQuery As String = "select * from tblproduct As p inner join tblbrand As b On p.bid = b.brandid inner Join tblclassification As c On p.cid = c.classid inner Join tblformulation As f On p.fid = f.formid inner Join tblgeneric As g On p.gid = g.genericid inner Join tbltype As t On p.tid = t.typeid"
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, cn)
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    While dr.Read
                        dt.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("barcode").ToString, dr.Item("generic").ToString, dr.Item("classification").ToString, dr.Item("type").ToString, dr.Item("formulation").ToString, dr.Item("price").ToString, dr.Item("qty").ToString)
                    End While
                    da.Fill(dt)

                    rptDataSource = New ReportDataSource("inventory", dt)

            End Select

            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub
End Class
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: One correction you should make is to explicitly name the fields. Avoid `SELECT *` in production code. Another thing would be to edit your post to identify the line that is throwing the Exception.

Comment: Aside from using Select * (bad practice), can you provide more details? You need to check output window for more detailed error. It's not even clear it's a report that gives you an error.